# Selenium WebDriver sendKeys() not working with oncopy, onpaste Javascript event

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dom-events

Html code:

```
<input type="text" class="input-txt" data-bind="value: Email,qtipValMessage:Email" id="txtEmail" maxlength="160" oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false" title="Please enter the Email" data-orig-title="">
```

My Java code:

```
WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.id("txtEmail"));
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(email).perform();
email.clear();
email.sendKeys("xyz@xyz.com");
```

While executing my code its provide an error message:

> "Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated"

because html code mapped with "oncopy" and "onpaste" tag (return false), so that `sendKeys()` failed during the execution.

Please help with how will we pass the value in this field.

Answer (score 0):

The regular Selenium api has a "set value" method.  I don't remember it off the top of my head but if you can't find it, you can always use a JavascriptExecutor as a workaround:

```
WebDriver driver; // Assigned elsewhere
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementByID('elID').setAttribute('value', val )");
```